# Sort dynamic headers of array with usort

Tags: php

I've got the following array, which results in

```
Loc    L    M   S   XS
001    2    3   3   1
006    0    2   3   1
012    2    2   2   2
```

I'm trying to sort the header of this array as following:
XS,S,M,L,XL (clothing sizes from small to extra large)

I've figured out how the usort function works with the sample code below, but I can't figure out how to implement this in my array, because I don't know how to identify the keys in my array L, M, S, XS?

sample:

```
<?php
$order = array("XS","S", "M", "L", "XL");
$array = array(
    array('id' => "M", 'title' => 'Some Title'),
    array('id' => "L", 'title' => 'Some Title'),
    array('id' => "S", 'title' => 'Some Title'),
    array('id' => "XL", 'title' => 'Some Title'),
);

usort($array, function ($a, $b) use ($order) {
    $pos_a = array_search($a['id'], $order);
    $pos_b = array_search($b['id'], $order);
    return $pos_a - $pos_b;
});

var_dump($array);
?>
```

The array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Loc] => 001
            [L] => 2
            [M] => 3
            [S] => 3
            [XS] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Loc] => 006
            [L] => 0
            [M] => 2
            [S] => 3
            [XS] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Loc] => 012
            [L] => 2
            [M] => 2
            [S] => 2
            [XS] => 2
        )

)
```

My php:

```
echo '<tr>';
//headers
foreach( $result as $key => $value )
{
    if( is_array($value) ) 
    { 
        foreach($value as $key => $column) {
            echo '  <th colspan="1" style="width: 30px">'.$key.'</th>';
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        echo '<th colspan="1">Niks</th>';
    }
    break;
}
echo '</tr>';
//Data
foreach( $result as $key => $value )
{
echo '<tr>';
    if( is_array($value) ) 
    { 
        foreach($value as $key => $column) {
            echo '<td>'.$column.'</td>';
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        echo '<td>'.$value.'</td>';
    }
echo '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: Can anyone help me how to implent the solution from user "Don't panic" into my code? When I use only your code, the "location code" header is gone and I'm not seeing the numeric clothing sizes anymore (36,37,38, etc). Thx!

Answer (score 2):

I actually wouldn't use `usort` for this. You can just output based on that `$order` array.

```
$order = array("XS","S", "M", "L", "XL");
```

For the headers, just iterate the order array and use those values in the `<th>`s.

```
echo '<tr>';
//headers
foreach($order as $key)
{
    echo '  <th colspan="1" style="width: 30px">'.$key.'</th>';
}
echo '</tr>';
```

For the data, iterate the order array for each row and use those order values as keys to access the values in the row.

```
//Data
foreach($result as $key => $row)
{
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach($order as $key) {
        echo '<td>' . ($row[$key] ?? '') . '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: Can you help me how to implent this into my code? When I use only your code, the "location code" header is gone and I'm not seeing the numeric clothing sizes anymore (36,37,38, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Building a template array for each row and then using [`array_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php) to copy the relevant parts across from each item should do the trick...

```
$result = Array
(
    Array
    (
        "Loc" => "001",
        "L" => 2,
        "M" => 3,
        "S" => 3,
        "XS" => 1
        ),
    Array
    (
        "Loc" => "006",
        "L" => 0,
        "M" => 2,
        "S" => 3,
        "XS" => 1
        ),
    Array
    (
        "Loc" => "012",
        "L" => 2,
        "M" => 2,
        "S" => 2,
        "XS" => 2
        )
    );

$order = array("Loc", "XS","S", "M", "L", "XL");
$order = array_fill_keys($order, 0);
$newResult = [];
foreach ( $result as $item )    {
    $newResult[] = array_replace($order, $item);
}
print_r($newResult);
```

Outputs...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Loc] => 001
            [XS] => 1
            [S] => 3
            [M] => 3
            [L] => 2
            [XL] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Loc] => 006
            [XS] => 1
            [S] => 3
            [M] => 2
            [L] => 0
            [XL] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Loc] => 012
            [XS] => 2
            [S] => 2
            [M] => 2
            [L] => 2
            [XL] => 0
        )

)
```